# HDMI output to DVI-D Input full HD?

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi, hdtv, high-definition

I have:

- A [Dell LCD back-light LED monitor](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&cs=19&sku=320-9791) which have VGA, DP and DVI-D input ports.
- And I have a [satellite receiver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxV6Z.jpg) that have a HDMI output and supports Full HD (1920x1080).

I want to connect my satellite receiver with monitor to use my monitor as a TV, so please help me regarding to this issue.

1. Is there:

   - Any cable/converter for HDMI output to DP input? *I think no.*
   - HDMI output to DVI-D input cable/converter?
2. I don't want to lose picture quality, so please tell me which one is better for 1920x1080p?

   - A adopter/converter (with a internal circuit)
   - A simple cable?

   I don't have issue with audio because there is another 3.5 mm jack on satellite receiver, that I will use as a audio output.
3. One more question, picture quality will be same as of HDMI to HDMI or will be lower due to conversion or any other issue?

So please guide me this will work? Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

There's no real difference between HDMI, DisplayPort and DVI-D at that resolution. Just get a passive HDMI-to-DisplayPort adapter, there's plenty of them. There is no loss in quality because both standards are digital.

Comment: whats mean by passive?

Comment: There is no integrated circuit involved in the conversion. See http://www.startech.com/faq/DisplayPort_Converter_DP_Multi_Mode

Comment: on google, i could not find any HDMI to DP adapter, if you can, please post a link